# Issue with displaying data returned from REST API using React

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am trying out some stuff using the react-chatbot-kit in the front end and getting data from a REST API. Console.log shows the data inside .then, however I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when trying to output the data on the console inside the calling function. I need help to display the returned data in console.log in the function handleApiList(). Thanks in advance.

PS: I am a newbie of course in React :) since I am not clear on how to handle REST API calls that are done asynchronously. Look forward to getting this resolved. Any help and tips on resolving this will be greatly appreciated

Following is the code:

```
// ActionProvider starter code
class ActionProvider {
  constructor(createChatBotMessage, setStateFunc) {
    this.createChatBotMessage = createChatBotMessage;
    this.setState = setStateFunc;
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      users: []
    }
  }

    greet() {
      const greetingMessage = this.createChatBotMessage("Hi! Greeting!")
      this.updateChatbotState(greetingMessage)
    }

    // This is being called when the user types in 'api' in chat window
    handleApiList()
    {
      const { error, users } = this.state;
      this.getData();
      if(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error.message)
      }
      else {
        let myarray=[]
        users.map(function(user)
        {
          myarray += `${ user.name }\n`;
          return `${ user.name }`;
        })
        console.log(myarray)
      }
    }

    getData()
    {
      console.log("in now")
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            this.setState({
              users: result
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
          }          
        )
      }

    handleJobList = () => {
      const message = this.createChatBotMessage(
        "Fantastic, I've got the following jobs available for you",
        {
          widget: "jobLinks",
        }
      );
  
      this.updateChatbotState(message);
    };

    updateChatbotState(message) {
      // NOTE: This function is set in the constructor, and is passed in
      // from the top level Chatbot component. The setState function here
      // actually manipulates the top level state of the Chatbot, so it's
      // important that we make sure that we preserve the previous state.
          
         this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState, messages: [...prevState.messages, message]
          }))
        }
      }
      
  export default ActionProvider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching in getData and it's an async function. The data is not ready. It's better to just return the data than to setting state.

simplified version of your code.

```
   handleApiList()
    {
      const { error, users } = this.state;
      const data = await this.getData();

      //data is ready, do what u want with the data here.
      }
    }

    const getData = async() => {

      return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(res => res.json())
              
        )
      }
```

.map returns an array, if you want to push u need to use forEach.

Example

```
    let myarray=[]
    data.forEach((user) =>
    {
      myarray.push(user.name });
    })
    console.log(myarray)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Someone Special! You really are someone special :) I'd been struggling with this since yesterday and it worked. In my case using <const> before getData did not work so removed that. Also made handleApiList as async and it worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue description:

```
const { error, users } = this.state; // gets state values
  this.getData();                    // updates state values
  if(error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error.message)
  }
  else {
    let myarray=[]
    users.map(function(user)         // users is value before state update
```

I would suggest returning from `getData()` a promise with result of api call. After that you can execute code in `handleApiList()` in `.then()`.

Proposal:

```
getData()
{
  console.log("in now")
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          users: result
        });

        return result;
      }         
    )
  }
```

I would also move error handling to `.catch()`.

Also have a look on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). Working using async/await instead of pure Promises is easier and cleaner ;)

Comment: Appreciate your response on the question Ogochi. The first answer posted by Someone Special worked so I honestly did not attempt doing it. Thanks :)